# Compile and Install old kernel on latest ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, ubuntu-18.04, boot

I want to compile and install kernel 3.10.61 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I compiled kernel 3.10.61 successfully.
(It didn't been compiled, so I downgraded my gcc to 4.4 from 7)

But, after I install the kernel using 'make install', the kernel is not booted up.

The booting is stopped printing a message "loading initial ramdisk".

Anyone know how to install old kernel on latest ubuntu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these instructions, assuming that you know how to download the kernel source code, and preparing the `make menuconfig`.

To compile the kernel:

> make -j$(nprocs)

To compile the new kernel modules:

> make modules -j$(nprocs)

To install the new kernel modules:

> sudo make modules_install

To install the new kernel:

> sudo make install

Then update your Grub table:

> sudo update-grub

After the reboot, you should hold the `shift` key during boot time.

Then, in the Grub menu, you can select the new kernel version to launch.

Comment: I already know how to compile and install kernel.
I'm asking solution of my problem, and problem is that old version kernel cannot be installed on latest ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am using Arch. If anyone has some questions, you can comment below or email me (PETERLITSZO at GMAIL COM). I will try to update this answer.

In my opinion, most OS will be loader by those steps:

1. BIOS will start GRUB, which is used to load other OS.
2. GRUB will load Linux kernel.
3. GRUB will load Linux initramfs, which is used to load other modules, devices and file systems.
4. Linux kernel will start by user `root`, and run `systemd` or something else.

Maybe you can follow this page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel/Traditional_compilation

I am not sure if the command `make install` is outdated.

The command `make install` will create a new kernel named `/boot/vmlinuz`, which cannot be found by GRUB.

I am using new kernel now by those steps:

1. Build a new kernel by `make`.
2. Build the new modules by `make modules_install`.
3. Copy the new kernel (in **my** device, it is `./arch/x86/boot/bzImage`) to folder `/boot`(I also rename this file, and now there is a new kernel named `/boot/vmlinuz-peterlits`. If you want to let GRUB find your kernel, you should name it `/boot/vmlinuz-<whatever you want>`).
4. But we do not have initramfs. If you are using Arch, you can follow this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel/Traditional_compilation#Make_initial_RAM_disk. Now we have a initramfs.
5. Then we need make GRUB know. Then we need use `grub-mkconfig` or `update-grub` (In my computer, there are same. Please search in web to get how to update GRUB).